# Git Branching Convention : Baseline from Dev or Master

Tags: git

When creating a new feature branch should I baseline from `master` branch or `dev` branch and why? I'm used to creating a branch from `master` as the baseline, making my changes and merging it back into `dev` but recently at my new organization it was suggested that I create the branch with `dev` as reference.

I both cases my primary branch was `master`. In the first situation, I would branch from `master`, do my changes, merge to `dev`, test it and once all this was done I would raise a PullRequest (PR) to `main` directly.

In the second situation, I'm supposed to branch from `dev`, do my changes and raise a PR to `dev`. If and when its approved its picked up for release and merged back into `master` during the release.

Comment: Master branch is the master

Comment: as a rule of thumb: merge from that branch into which you want to merge later. This minimizes the chance of merge conflicts.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/131171/53019

Comment: I've reverted the `master` -> `main` change here purely because everything else around this (the title, the comments and all answers) still refer to `master` and it's very confusing to read with a mix of terminology. For avoidance of doubt, I'm fully in favour of `main` for any new questions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking if you have a `master` branch and a `development` branch, and you're following some process (instead of randomly doing things in git), you are most likely expected to branch from `dev` instead of `master`.

This is because `master` (or `trunk` or `main` or whatever it's named) should represent a very stable state of code, ideally the same as the last release. On the other hand if you don't release often, and are working with multiple developers, the development branch could contain a lot of changes and be very different from master. Since you (hopefully) won't merge directly to master, you could end up developing on top of "stale" code (from master) and when merging to development you would notice that "oh no, I've written code that doesn't fit well with the code in development".

Since development will most likely be merged back to master to represent the new "release state", branching off of development allows you to develop on top of more up-to-date code than if you were to branch off of master. This means you'll have less merge conflicts.

There are different factors that affect how much of a difference this makes (e.g. if you have a daily build/release cycle, your master and development will never be very far from each other), but this is one logical reason (and not just a convention) why development should be used instead of master for branch root.

---

What I've described is your second situation, which follows [gitflow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) at least in principle.  Your first situation describes a different branching model. Git doesn't mandate that you do things in a specific way, but time has taught effective processes to use.

In your first situation you have to make sure that dev and master are synchronized, so you don't test code in dev that would then break in master. This may not be an issue, and it may be completely intentional if short release cycles are to be used. It may also mean that development can be "broken", if the idea is that features are pushed to dev and automated testing is done on that branch when new code is pushed. Ideally you wouldn't risk pushing broken code to dev, running tests locally before pushing, but if for example the test set is heavy, it might not be possible.

**TL;DR** a suitable branching model depends on a whole lot of things, such as the length of the release cycle, the amount of testing done, the amount of developers and of course the nature of the system. There are conventions and processes that are developed to minimize the complexity of multiple developers working on the same codebase, but there are no strict rules except for one.

"DON'T BREAK MASTER!".

Comment: In open source projects you often have contributors which are not familiar with that concept. And you can not expect they read your `CONTRIBUTE.md` file. You can be happy to even have a contributor. So how do I setup a project that way that feature/bugfix branches are based on `dev` instead of `main`.

Comment: I don't believe ""DON'T BREAK MASTER!". is always such a strict rule. If you have robust quality checks (whether automated or manual) between master and production then having master briefly broken is not a disaster.

Fowler's CI certification cartoon doesn't say master must never be broken, it says it should be fixed within 10 minutes if it is broken.

Comment: If it is allowed to be broken for ten minutes then it isn’t “master”. Master should from time to time be replaced with a version of the development branch that survived production for some time.

Comment: @gnasher729 It's definitely not a universal rule of git usage that there is a development branch and a master branch. You can see the CI certification cartoon here: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContinuousIntegrationCertification.html

Answer (score 5):

Ultimately it's up to your organization how they choose to organize their branches.

From Git's point of view, the name **master** is just a convention.  It doesn't matter.  Instead of **master**, your main branch could be **dev** or **baseline** or **purple-elephants**.  It makes no difference to how Git works.

So if your organization says to branch off **dev**, then do that.

Comment: It's not necessarily *just* a convention. If you're using gitflow, `master` and `development` have strict rules (well conventions, but if you break them why use gitflow at all) about where to branch from / merge to. Of course if you're not following a particular branching model, then you can do whatever you want. This doesn't really answer the "why" of the question. Also note how he said he's used to branching from master and merging to dev.

Comment: No, it really is just a convention.  You can name your Git branches any way you want to.  Gitflow has its own conventions, and again, they're just conventions.  Anyway we have no way of knowing what rules his organization is following that require the conventions they use.

Comment: @Kayaman hmm let me rephrase my question.

Comment: Since the names of the branches are irrelevant, would you say that switching the names `master` and `development` with each other would be perfectly acceptable?

Comment: "Irrelevant" is a term no one used here.  Better to say that the names have meaning within context, and one development team's context will differ from another's, so they will choose names that have relevance to themselves.

Comment: Yes, names convey meaning. But you seem to suggest that development teams just invent their own git processes and naming, which I certainly hope is not common in 2019. Saying "just do as you're told" doesn't give much insight into *why* you might be instructed to branch from / merge to a specific branch.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to say that every single development shop in the world should work exactly the same way or what.  But I'm not going to argue with you about it anymore.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm curious whether you've noticed that in 2020, a number of organizations have been [changing `master` to something like `main` or `trunk` because of ostensibly offensive connotations of the word "master."](https://www.theregister.com/2020/06/15/github_replaces_master_with_main)  However one might feel about this, it nicely illustrates my point: The name `master` literally does not matter.  It is _merely_ a convention that can easily be (and has been) replaced with a different convention.

Comment: I'd hardly consider that the same thing. I see `master/main/trunk` as synonyms. In the question it's a difference between `master/dev`. They're semantically completely different. The names are meaningless yes, but they're used to convey meaning. It helps when that meaning is understood by everyone such as `production/development`, instead of `green/purple`.